# NoSQL key value scalable database with scan

Tags: database, scale, key-value-store, nosql

I am currently looking at different No SQL scalable database. I am surprise to see that both HBase and Cassandra which are column based No SQL database, make effort to keep row with cloth key on the same node and therefore provide efficient scan request.
By scan request, I mean getting all the document which have key in a specific range.
Unfortunately, I am looking for a key value database because of some restriction on the format of my value.
And, as far as I know, there is no mature key-value database that scale efficiently that support scan ?
Moreover i read Google's paper on Big Table, and I think it's possible to port the scan feature on key-value storage.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "scan"? Searching the database by a non-indexed value?

Comment: I just edited my question. By scan i mean when you want to fetch all the data which have a key between X and Y

Comment: Can you precise that the database must be distributed. In that case there is the new sql database TiDB and CockroachDB. They are not KV stores but they can act like it.